# How to set and access response of python code in next step in github workflow

Tags: python, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

How to set and access the response of python code to a variable in github workflow. I have to use the token which is generated from the python code in the step Create container web in the Auth_Header

```
- name: setup python
    uses: actions/setup-python@v2
    with:
      python-version: '3.9.0'

  - name: Get Token
    run: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      pip install requests-oauthlib
      pip install Authlib
      python -c 'from authlib.integrations.requests_client import OAuth2Session;
      session = OAuth2Session("${{ env.CLIENT_ID }}", "${{ env.CLIENT_SECRET }}")
      session.fetch_token("${{ env.TOKEN_ENDPOINT }}")
      session.token["access_token"]'

  - name: Create Container Web
      #if: steps.pr-label.outputs.result == 'true'
    run: |
        AUTH_HEADER="Authorization: token $access_token"
```

so far what I have tried is below but still it is not working

```
- name: Get Token
        env:
          ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS: 'true'
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install requests-oauthlib
          pip install Authlib
          echo ::set-env name=ACCESS_TOKEN::$(python -c 'from authlib.integrations.requests_client import OAuth2Session;
          session = OAuth2Session("${{ env.CLIENT_ID }}", "${{ env.CLIENT_SECRET }}")
          session.fetch_token("${{ env.TOKEN_ENDPOINT }}")
          session.token["access_token"]')
        id: token

      - name: Create Container Web
          #if: steps.pr-label.outputs.result == 'true'
        run: |
            echo token is ${{ env.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
            AUTH_HEADER="Authorization: token ${{ env.ACCESS_TOKEN }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set an output using `::set-output` and then get this output back in the next step using `steps.[id].outputs.ACCESS_TOKEN`:

```yaml
name: Token

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Get Token
        env:
          ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS: 'true'
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install requests-oauthlib
          pip install Authlib
          echo ::set-output name=ACCESS_TOKEN::$(python 'from authlib.integrations.requests_client import OAuth2Session;
          session = OAuth2Session("${{ env.CLIENT_ID }}", "${{ env.CLIENT_SECRET }}")
          session.fetch_token("${{ env.TOKEN_ENDPOINT }}")
          print(session.token["access_token"])')
        id: token
      - name: Create Container Web
        run: |
            echo token is ${{ steps.token.outputs.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
            AUTH_HEADER="Authorization: token ${{ steps.token.outputs.ACCESS_TOKEN }}"
```

Comment: Thanks Bertrand it worked like a charm!! do I need to use print statement at the end..

Comment: @Tim the print statement is to send the value to stdout so that the result of $(...) will be "token"

Comment: is it safe to use print in the console

Comment: @Tim what do you mean by safe? for the access token ? I would say that it's as safe as  `echo` but the risk would be script injection if it outputs some command like "ls", it will resolve to `$("ls")` etc... The risk is the same as `echo ${{ ..... }}`. You need to check that `session.token["access_token"]` is a valid formatted access token for example. See [this doc about the risk of script injections](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#understanding-the-risk-of-script-injections).